# Portable Git repository on USB drive, submodule setup

Tags: git

I created a bare repo on my us drive, using

```
git init --bare M:\usb_repo
```

and on my local repo I added the usb repo and an additional remote using

```
git remote add usb M:/usb_repo
```

And I can push/pull to the portable repo from my local system and I can take my portable repo to another system and checkout from the portable repo just fine. My issue is submodules. The repo I', working with uses submodules and I'm unsure of how I deal with them while using a portable repo. I thought maybe going into the local submodule folder/repo and doing the same process of adding the usb as a remote would work, but apparently not.

Is there a specific way of doing this?

Comment: @VonC's answer is good. I just want to add: in my `.gitmodules`, I say `url = ../otherrepo.git`. When the repo is on a remote, it fetches the modules from the same remote, and when the repo is on a drive or other local path, it fetches the modules from sibling directories, which should work for you.

Comment: Minor comment: I would call the repo `M:\usb_repo.git`, to make its nature clearer when you encounter it, but it should work either way.

Answer (score 1):

If those submodules, registered in the `.gitmodules` file of your parent repository, reference external public repository URLs, you don't have anything to do.

If there are referencing other local repositories, then I would use7

- either the same kind of absolute path as the one for the main repo (`M:\myProject1.git/`, as bare repository)
- or a relative URL (but in your case, an absolute path to the external drive is preferable)

Comment: I think I understand, but I'm a little confused by what my `.gitmodules` contains. The submodules in question are external but in the .gitmodules file, the url listed for each submodule is something like `url = ../../name.git` Is this supposed to point to the remote, external url? In the root `.git` folder under modules and module name in the `config` file, it does list the remote origin url which is what I expect for the external repo. The portable git repo that sits on the usb would be used to help with a disconnected system.

Comment: @n1th6 The URL for a submodule can reference a remote or local repository. In your case, a bare repository stored locally, in ../..